# GTK file/folder tree view: enable only highlighting/selecting file name

Tags: linux, file-manager, nautilus

since this is my first question here, I hope I do not distract you ;-)

I have wondered for a long time now wether there was an option in any
GTK setting that allows me (p.ex. in Nautilus) to select only the file's
or folder's name in an expanded tree view, *NOT* like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fkeit8nk6ezhjnv/BadNautilus.png?dl=0

But more like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/52b9iv2lz0zvahl/GoodSystem7.png?dl=0

In the top picture you see that I wanted to get the context menu of
my home folder while I had the "Downloads" folder expanded, p.ex.
for opening a terminal.

If a (right-)click in the middle of nowhere would be taken as being directed at the current view's top level folder (in this example, my home folder), opening a terminal wouldn't be that of a problem.

Another example: Suppose I wanted to add a new file by selecting right click->New document->... (any template here). This is not possible in a folder
where I have to scroll down because it has so much content in it.

So summing it up:
There are context menu actions that "belong" to the empty screen space in a folder view below the listed files (at least in Nautilus) that I also want to be able to use in a folder which is so crowded that there is no more empty screen space. I know some, at least System 7 finder and Win (up to XP), file managers which are capable of this. Is it possible to system-wide set
the screen space next to the file name string to be equivalent to the empty screen space below a file listing?

Any ideas?

Best regards,
 JohnS